# fadeIn and fadeOut not working

Tags: jquery

I'm messing around with a one page site. I'm looking to have divs fade in and out on click events in the nav. The .currentPage will be showing on load, and fade out when other nav a's are clicked. I have it up on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexwcoleman/95d6V/).

Issues:

1. fadeOut doesn't happen
2. fadeIn only happens after you've clicked nav a's a couple of times.
3. Ideally, I'd like it so that if you click whichever nav a is .current, nothing happens - Right now if you click, it runs the script again.

Wishlist:

1. is there a more succinct jQuery method for fading divs in and out via the nav? I'm just kind of fumbling around and don't have much clue...

HTML

```
<nav>
    <a href="#" id="workPage" class="current">Work</a>
    <a href="#" id="aboutPage">About</a>
    <a href="#" id="designPage">Design</a>
</nav>

<div class="box work currentPage">WORK</div>
<div class="box about">ABOUT</div>
<div class="box design">DESIGN</div>
```

jQuery

```
$('nav a').click(function () {
    if (!$(this).hasClass("current")) {
        $('.current').removeClass("current");
        $(this).addClass("current");
    }

}); //using this to set a "current" state in the nav


$("#workPage").click(function () {
    $('.currentPage').fadeOut(500, function (){
        $('.work').addClass('currentPage').fadeIn(500);
        }).removeClass('currentPage');
    });


$("#aboutPage").click(function () {
    $('.currentPage').fadeOut(500, function (){
        $('.about').addClass('currentPage').fadeIn(500);
    }).removeClass('currentPage');
});

$("#designPage").click(function () {
    $('.currentPage').fadeOut(500, function (){
        $('.design').addClass('currentPage').fadeIn(500);
    }).removeClass('currentPage');
});
```

Comment: try this: remove `.remocClass('currentPage')` from every click event and add to box css `position:absolute;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove the current class in the complete callback

```
$('nav a').click(function (e) {
    if (!$(this).hasClass("current")) {
        $('.current').removeClass("current");
        $(this).addClass("current");
    } else {
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    }

});


$("#workPage").click(function () {
    $('.currentPage').fadeOut(500, function (){
        $(this).removeClass('currentPage')
        $('.work').addClass('currentPage').fadeIn(1000);
    });
});


$("#aboutPage").click(function () {
    $('.currentPage').fadeOut(500, function (){
        $(this).removeClass('currentPage')
        $('.about').addClass('currentPage').fadeIn(1000);
    })
});

$("#designPage").click(function () {
    $('.currentPage').fadeOut(500, function (){
        $(this).removeClass('currentPage')
        $('.design').addClass('currentPage').fadeIn(1000);
    })
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/sMZz5/)

Comment: Thanks @Arun, this is very close! The fadeIn still doesn't work until the nav a's have been clicked three times... which is odd! Any ideas?.... edit --> I added another nav a, and now the fadeIn takes four clicks to start working...